# Syncfusion DataManager makes request constantly against its API, react scheduler component

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion, syncfusion-datamanager, syncfusion-scheduler

Is there a way to put a timer/delay/interval on DataManager?  I have syncfusion scheduler with a DataManager for CRUD operations.  It makes constant request to the Api to get appointments for the calendar.  I don't really need calendar refreshes more often then every few minutes.

Here is my code to create the datamanger

```
const dataManager=new DataManager({
  url: GetEventEndpoint(userContext.user.Id), // 'controller/actions'
  crudUrl: PostEventEndpoint(userContext.user.Id),
  adaptor: new UrlAdaptor,
  crossDomain:true,
  
});

const eventSettings = { dataSource: dataManager/* , fields: fields */ }
```

Here is also the react scheduler component

```
<ScheduleComponent width='100%' height='550px' eventSettings={eventSettings}>
                      <ViewsDirective>
                        <ViewDirective option='Day' />
                        <ViewDirective option='Week' />
                        <ViewDirective option='WorkWeek' />
                        <ViewDirective option='Month' />
                      </ViewsDirective>
                      <Inject services={[Day, Week, WorkWeek, Month]} />
                    </ScheduleComponent>
```

Below are the snap shot of the log from the API on requests being made to the API.

```
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.568Z] Executed 'events' (Succeeded, Id=4291aff0-76f6-41f7-a510-f0fc598b2185, Duration=5ms)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.569Z] Executing 'events' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=7fb0d73a-4faf-4e4d-82a7-3cdf3c57e6ac)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.571Z] Executed 'events' (Succeeded, Id=7fb0d73a-4faf-4e4d-82a7-3cdf3c57e6ac, Duration=2ms)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.574Z] Executing 'events' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=558acd63-2f22-4682-b29c-5a1c3db70c26)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.577Z] Executed 'events' (Succeeded, Id=558acd63-2f22-4682-b29c-5a1c3db70c26, Duration=2ms)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.578Z] Executing 'events' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=85e3e126-6a17-4b24-bbba-95aceb88a78c)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.582Z] Executed 'events' (Succeeded, Id=85e3e126-6a17-4b24-bbba-95aceb88a78c, Duration=3ms)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.583Z] Executing 'events' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=09985982-5fbf-4402-a10c-8a4ed0c5480b)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.585Z] Executed 'events' (Succeeded, Id=09985982-5fbf-4402-a10c-8a4ed0c5480b, Duration=1ms)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.587Z] Executing 'events' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=3f2c711a-e323-4301-9997-8f2680582efc)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.589Z] Executed 'events' (Succeeded, Id=3f2c711a-e323-4301-9997-8f2680582efc, Duration=1ms)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.593Z] Executing 'events' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=dc404f46-0b7e-4fa8-bcc2-ef2bde94a74a)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.595Z] Executing 'events' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=3e4208dc-6bf3-4d0f-8003-5c0df5bc0ef0)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.597Z] Executed 'events' (Succeeded, Id=dc404f46-0b7e-4fa8-bcc2-ef2bde94a74a, Duration=4ms)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.599Z] Executed 'events' (Succeeded, Id=3e4208dc-6bf3-4d0f-8003-5c0df5bc0ef0, Duration=3ms)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.601Z] Executing 'events' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=07999e67-207c-4847-8627-4eee76ea3d0a)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.603Z] Executed 'events' (Succeeded, Id=07999e67-207c-4847-8627-4eee76ea3d0a, Duration=1ms)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.604Z] Executing 'events' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=5bd234d9-19d4-4460-8568-6a19da0c50c0)
[2023-11-28T03:18:53.607Z] Executed 'events' (Succeeded, Id=5bd234d9-19d4-4460-8568-6a19da0c50c0, Duration=2ms)
```

I would like to know what is there a way to change the request to every 60 seconds or only on when the page loads?